# Is there a performance disadvantage to not copying reference types to each thread in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, cpu-cache

I am working on implementing threading to my C# program. Each thread requires access to the same array, but does not need to write to it, only read data. Should this array be deep copied for each thread?

The reason I think this might be important (from my very limited knowledge of threading) is so that threads on different CPU cores can store copies of the array in their own cache instead of constantly requesting data from a single core's cache where the array is stored, but perhaps the compiler or something else will optimise away this inefficiency?

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you include in the question some code showing how each thread gets access to the array? For example is it passed as a parameter through the `ParameterizedThreadStart` delegate?

Comment: Don't help, a processor already knows how to do this by itself.

Comment: From what you describe, I see no reason to copy the array in multiple copies other than to reduce memory speed and performance, depending on the size and number of copies and how often you make those copies. Especially if you are just reading.

Comment: Read about [MESI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol), the assumption that only one core "owns" read-only data is not correct.

Comment: The answer to this should be, Benchmark this your self.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since you haven't specified the hardware architecture you are running on I'm going to assume it is either and Intel or AMD x64 processor. In which case I recommend trusting the processor to correctly optimize this situation. By creating multiple copies that the processor that the compiler can't know are duplicate copies you will force the processor to use more memory and spread the available cache space over more memory lessening it's effectiveness.